# Can I refer to the default target on the "make" command line?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

If I type just

```
$ make
```

it will invoke the `make` command with the default target (typically the first target specified in the `Makefile`, but the rules are a bit more complicated than that).

Is there a way to specify the default target on the command line without knowing what it is, other than by simply omitting the target name?

What I'd like to be able to do is combine these two commands:

```
$ make clean
$ make
```

into a single invocation of `make`.  If I happen to know that the default target is `all`, I can type:

```
$ make clean all
```

but that doesn't work if I don't know what the default target is.

Ideally, I'd like some syntax that refers to the default target (the [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) calls it the "default goal").  This:

```
 $ make clean .DEFAULT_GOAL
```

shows the general idea, but it doesn't work.

Second best would be a simple and reliable way to determine, from the command line, what the default target is:

```
$ make clean $(get-default-target)
```

A GNU-specific solution would be ok.

I suspect, from a quick look into the manual, that there's no good way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a shot at the second-best solution, you can parse the default goal from the output of make -pq:

```
make -pq  | sed -ne 's/^.DEFAULT_GOAL := //p'
```

Comment: That could be what I'm looking for. With `make -pq 2>/dev/null | sed -ne 's/^.DEFAULT_GOAL := //p'`, I get `default`. The only problem: I get it three times. I don't know whether there are circumstances where it might show more than one *distinct* target. But grabbing just the first line will probably do.

Comment: I've written a small script, `make-target`, that invokes `make -pq 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/^.DEFAULT_GOAL := /{s///p;q;}'`. Sample usage: `make clean $(make-target)`. I've also written another shell script, `make2`, that avoids the issue altogether; it just does `make clean` followed by `make`. (Actually it's `make real-clean`.) The latter seems to be more convenient, and the overhead of invoking `make` twice is trivial.

Comment: After 3+ years, I suppose I should accept this answer. Thanks.