# How to explicitly call the default target when calling make?

Tags: makefile

Suppose my Makefile has the first target called "all", and so this is the default target. Then suppose I have a "clean" target, too.
If I want to issue a "rebuild" command I can write:

```
make clean all
```

and they will be called in sequence. But suppose I don't want to explicitly name the "all" target and let make use the default one, like usually you do:

```
make
```

Now, how to implement the "rebuild" command using the default? It should be something like:

```
make clean .DEFAULT_GOAL
```

but that special variable does not work from command line.

It's little more than a curiosity, because one could define a "rebuild" target in the Makefile and use that variable (or type "make clean && make"), but is it possible in some way?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There was a "Hi, " at the beginning of the question, but the site keeps cutting it away, sorry if it seems a little unpolite.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I refer to the default target on the "make" command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611372/can-i-refer-to-the-default-target-on-the-make-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to put a generic target name on the command line which means "the default target", without knowing the name of the default target and using that.

If that's what you're asking.

Comment: Yes exactly that, it seemed strange to me that a rather complex program lacked that feature.

Comment: I've never heard anyone ever ask for it before, and I've been using make for a _really_ long time.  It's actually not very useful to run a command like `make clean all` (or its equivalent, if such existed), at least not on modern build systems where parallel builds is supported.  I think most people prefer to run two distinct commands or, if this is something people often want to do, create a specific rule in the makefile to do it (where it can be done correctly from a parallel build perspective).